# Connect to Microsoft Graph from MVC on behalf of logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an MVC web app, that has certain pages that require a user to be logged in. The app is multitenant, and the authentication is configured in the Startup.Auth.cs. The ConfigureAuth file looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app){
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"],                
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters{
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications(){
            SecurityTokenValidated = (context) => {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => {
                var code = context.Code;

                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                    aadInstance + tenantID,
                    new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID)
                );
                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    code,
                    new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"]),
                    credential,
                    graphResourceID
                );

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            AuthenticationFailed = (context) => {
                context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This works - perfectly. My problem is, I would love to this the same authorization in my controller, when calling a Microsoft Graph endpoint.

I can see that the AccessToken contained in the AuthenticationResult has the correct scopes - meaning I should be able to reuse this when calling Graph, right?

But how do I use this in my controller? And how do I ensure the token is refreshed?

All examples I can find either use MSAL with v2 endpoint, or connects on behalf of the client - this does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reuse the token from within your controller and send it to graph so that graph thinks you are the user. This doesn't work, cause the token also contains the ip address of the client and that is not the ip address where your controller runs (well maybe only on your developer machine). Instead your application must have the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission.

If you have this, within your backend you can create a

`new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/")`

and call [`AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scope, clientCredentials, userAssertation)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_UserAssertion_).

- In this case the `scope` has to be `https://graph.microsoft.com/`.
- `clientCredentials` must contain your application id and secret.
- `userAssertation` must contain

  - the user token as assertation
  - the type should be `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer`
  - the username must be the users UPN

When this call returns, you'll get a new token. This can be used in graph calls as bearer token from your controller code to access resources as the user itself would do it.

But ensure that this token doesn't leak out of your control (like the application secret). Cause as long as this token doesn't expire it can be used from any machine in the world to act as the user.

### Update

If you don't have a user token, you need an application token to access the graph api. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow you can get a token for your application by calling

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
        { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"},
        { "client_id", "<ApplicationId>" },
        { "client_secret", "<ApplicationSecret>" }
    };

    var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic answer = JObject.Parse(content);

    return answer.access_token;
}
```

When you send this token to graph in the authorization header with the prefix `Bearer` you should be able to access all resources within the given tenant, which have been granted to your application.

Comment: That seems to make sense. The only thing I can't figure out is where you get the user token from? Is that from the AuthenticationResult? If so, what is the best way to store this?

Comment: Normally the JWT was given from Microsoft to Client and then redirects back to your application url. This web page (on the client) has to make a GET call to your controller (on the server) and sends the token (maybe as auth header bearer token?). Then in your controller you can grab this token and proceed as described above. No need to store the token anywhere.

Comment: I tried accessing the code from HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"], but it seems this header is not present. I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand how to retrieve this token in the first place.

Comment: The question is, what kind of user login do you use? I thought you would follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user In that case you should somewhere (on the client side) have a user token and that must be send to the backend, so this can get the BehalfOf token.

Comment: I pretty much use the user login in the Startup.auth as posted above. I was aiming to use the GraphServiceClient from the backend to pull data from Graph. Therefore, in this scenario, I do not use the frontend.

Comment: After your update, I got it to work! It took me a while to realize the tenantId could not be common, but had to be the ID of the requester. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @anl_extrico: Good to hear. And yes, due to the fact, that your app is multi-tenant you must provide the correct id instead of "common".

Comment: How to save the token ;  when i restart  iis    and i am logged in when i refersh i get error  page